# Changing the output sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that will give the count based on some filter according to the date.
But the problem is I want to change the destination where the O/P gets pasted.

Currently the calculation is done on "Latency" sheet and the O/P is paste there itself. I just want to change the output to cell AE5 in sheet"WBR45"

```
Option Explicit

Const strFormTitle = "Enter Minimum and Maximum Dates in d/m/yyyy format"  'Edit for different regional date format
Const strShtName As String = "Latency"              'Name of worksheet with  ranges to be processed
Const strDateFormat As String = "d mmm yyyy"       'Edit for different regional date format
Const strCrit1 As String = "Pass, Fail, In Progress"    'Criteria for output to AE2. (Can insert or delete criteria with comma between values. OK to have spaces with the commas)
Const strCrit2 As String = "COMPATIBLE"     'Criteria for column E. (One criteria only)
Const strDateRng As String = "K:K"      'Column with Dates
Const strCrit1Col As String = "O:O"     'Column with "Pass, Fail, In Progress"
Const strCrit2Col As String = "E:E"     'Column with "COMPATIBLE"
Const strOutput1 As String = "AE2"      'The cell for output "Pass, Fail, In Progress"
Const strOutput2 As String = "AF2"      'The cell for output "Pass, Fail, In Progress" plus "COMPATIBLE"



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.lblTitle = strFormTitle
End Sub

Private Sub cmdProcess_Click()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDates As Range       'Range of dates
    Dim rngCrit1 As Range       'Range to match Criteria 1
    Dim rngCrit2 As Range       'Range to match Criteria 2
    Dim dteMin As Date
    Dim dteMax As Date
    Dim rngOutput1 As Range
    Dim rngOutput2 As Range
    Dim arrSplit As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set ws = Worksheets(strShtName)
    With ws
        Set rngDates = .Columns(strDateRng)
        Set rngOutput1 = .Range(strOutput1)
        Set rngOutput2 = .Range(strOutput2)
        Set rngCrit1 = .Range(strCrit1Col)
        Set rngCrit2 = .Range(strCrit2Col)
    End With

    dteMin = CDate(Me.txtMinDate)
    dteMax = Int(CDate(Me.txtMaxDate) + 1)

    If dteMin > dteMax Then
        MsgBox "Minimum date must be less than maximum date." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please re-enter a valid dates."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    arrSplit = Split(strCrit1, ",")

    'Following loop removes any additional leading or trailing spaces (Can be in the string constant)
    For i = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
        arrSplit(i) = Trim(arrSplit(i))
    Next i

    rngOutput1.ClearContents 'Start with blank cell
    For i = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
    rngOutput1.Value = rngOutput1.Value + wf.CountIfs(rngDates, ">=" & CLng(dteMin), _
                rngDates, "<" & CLng(dteMax), _
                rngCrit1, arrSplit(i))
    Next i

    rngOutput2.ClearContents    'Start with blank cell
    For i = LBound(arrSplit) To UBound(arrSplit)
    rngOutput2.Value = rngOutput2.Value + wf.CountIfs(rngDates, ">=" & CLng(dteMin), _
                rngDates, "<" & CLng(dteMax), _
                rngCrit1, arrSplit(i), rngCrit2, strCrit2)
    Next i

End Sub


Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub txtMinDate_AfterUpdate()
    If IsDate(Me.txtMinDate) Then
        Me.txtMinDate = Format(CDate(Me.txtMinDate), strDateFormat)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Minimum date. Please re-enter a valid date."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtMaxDate_AfterUpdate()

    If IsDate(Me.txtMaxDate) Then
        Me.txtMaxDate = Format(CDate(Me.txtMaxDate), strDateFormat)
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Maximum date. Please re-enter a valid date."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub chkEntireRng_Click()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDates As Range

    Set wf = WorksheetFunction
    Set ws = Worksheets(strShtName)
    With ws
        Set rngDates = .Columns(strDateRng)
    End With
    If Me.chkEntireRng = True Then
        Me.txtMinDate = Format(wf.Min(rngDates), strDateFormat)
        Me.txtMaxDate = Format(wf.Max(rngDates), strDateFormat)
        Me.txtMinDate.Enabled = False
        Me.txtMaxDate.Enabled = False
    Else
        Me.txtMinDate = ""
        Me.txtMaxDate = ""
        Me.txtMinDate.Enabled = True
        Me.txtMaxDate.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If your code was indented it would be a lot easier to read - and you'd be more likely to get help

Comment: This: "But don't just copy in your entire program!" from here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot could be done to streamline and simplify this code, but in the current context, this is what I think you need to do.

After

```
Const strShtName As String = "Latency"
```

add

```
Const StrOPName as string = "WBR45"
```

change

```
Const strOutput1 As String = "AE2"
```

to

```
Const strOutput1 As String = "AE5"
```

and I guess change

```
Const strOutput2 As String = "AF2"
```

to

```
`Const strOutput2 As String = "AF5"`  'not sure if this is what you want as well
```

add

```
Dim wsOP As Worksheet
```

after

```
dim ws as worksheeet
```

and
set `wsOP = sheets (strOPname)`
after `set ws = worksheets (strShtName)`

take this out of the "with ws" section

```
Set rngOutput1 = .Range(strOutput1)
Set rngOutput2 = .Range(strOutput2)
```

and add this after the "End With"

```
Set rngOutput1 = wsOP.Range(strOutput1)
Set rngOutput2 = wsOP.Range(strOutput2)
```

Then, when the rngoutput1.value statement is reached, the target range will be wsOP.range ("AE5")

and the rngoutput2.value will move to AF5
I think that's what you need.  fiddle with it a bit.